# How can I save my processed images in an output folder to be as sorted as they are in the input folder?

Tags: python, string, sorting, path

I tried to get the edges of some images and output them in a separate folder, but the output files do not correspond to the input files. Please, how can I correct this?

Below is my code:

```
import glob
import cv2
import os

in_path = "E:\\datasets\\malayakew\\b\\*.jpg"

out_path = "E:\\datasets\\malayakew\\a\\"

cv_img = []

img_path = sorted(glob.glob(in_path))

for i, img in enumerate(img_path):
    n= cv2.imread(img)
    cv_img.append(n)
          
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(n, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    edge = cv2.Canny(gray, 255, 255)
      
    cv2.imwrite(out_path + f'{str(i+1)}.jpg', edge)
    
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The code runs without an error, however, most of the output images do not correspond with the input images. Here are samples of the result:

[image: original images]

[image: output images]

Comment: Why is there a `+1` in `cv2.imwrite(out_path + f'{str(i+1)}.jpg', edge)`? If it's because the image indices start at 1 rather than at 0, then you can use `enumerate(img_path, start=1)` instead of adding +1 to every occurrence of `i`. Also, you don't need both `str( )` and `f'{ }'`. You can write either `str(i) + '.jpg'` or `f'{i}.jpg'`.

Comment: @Stef, because the results begin from 0,1,2,3,........ So I added the one for the output to start from #1

Comment: It looks like `sorted(glob.glob(in_path))` doesn't sort the images in the order than you believe it sorts them. Can you print the list `glob.glob(in_path)`?

Comment: If I would guess I would say it's because the numbers that appear in the strings don't all have the same number of digits. For instance, try `print(sorted(map(str, range(22))))`. You'll understand what is going on.

Comment: Instead of using `enumerate(...)` and hoping that the indices will match the numbers in the names of the input files, I suggest using [`os.path.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) to get the filenames of the input files and use that name directly for the output.

Comment: @Stef, you're absolutely right, the ```sorted(glob.glob(in_path)) didn't really have the effect I expected. On printing the list, I discovered the following arrangement:
```1,10,11,12,........```   instead of     ```1,2,3,4,...``` as I expected.

I would try the other suggestions you gave in a bit...

Comment: Also I strongly recommend using `os.path.join` and `os.path.split` rather than any manual string manipulation of paths. Imagine someone runs your code on another computer. If you have used `os.path` functions, they will only have to modify `out_path = "E:\\datasets\\malayakew\\a\\"` into `out_path = 'correct/path/on/their/computer'`. But if you have manipulated strings manually, for instance using `+`, it might break and it will be hard to debug. Or if you later write  `out_path = "E:\\datasets\\malayakew\\a"` without the last `\\ ` it will break. But if you use `os.path` it won't break

Answer (score 0):

You're hoping that by sorting the list of paths in `glob.glob(in_path)` and then using `enumerate`, the indices will match the numbers in the filenames.

This is dubious. In particular, you're trying to sort a list of ***strings*** which contain numbers. Try the following experiment:

```py
print(sorted(map(str, range(14))))
# ['0', '1', '10', '11', '12', '13', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
```

Note how all numbers which begin with the digit `'1'` appear before all numbers which begin with the digit `'2'`. In particular, `10` appears before `2`.

Now, there are tricks to sort strings that contain numbers. But this is not what you need. What you need is to not sort at all, and not use `enumerate` at all. Don't try to guess the numbers from the sorting. Instead, just copy the filenames. You can use [`os.path.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) to extract the filename from the path of the input file, then use [`os.path.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to rebuild the path of the output file.

```py
img_paths = sorted(glob.glob(in_path))

for img_path in img_paths:
    n = cv2.imread(img_path)
    cv_imgs.append(n)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(n, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    edge = cv2.Canny(gray, 255, 255)
    _, img_filename = os.path.split(img_path)
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(out_path, img_filename), edge)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: You're absolutely right. Using the image filenames was a better option. This worked perfectly. Thanks alot @Stef